# Why does Yeoman build without glyphicons?

Tags: deployment, fonts, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm working on a `webapp` generator and after running `grunt` I got a functional app which display fonts correctly. However, when I check in the `dist/` directory I don't get any fonts files.

The docs state that `grunt` command `build the application for deployment`, but the `dist/` directory isn't autonomous.

### Gruntfile.js config

My `copy:dist` task is as follow:

```
dist: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
        ]
    }]
},
```

So it does copy font, but not the glyphicons one which is in `bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/fonts/`

### Build content

Here is all I got after running `grunt build`

```
./dist
├── 404.html
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── robots.txt
├── scripts
│   ├── coffee.js
│   ├── plugins.js
│   ├── vendor.js
│   └── main.js
└── styles
    └── main.css
```

### Question

So how do I create a deployment directory containing all files and resources ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug Sindre mentioned has now been fixed. You can either start a new project with `generator-webapp` >= 0.4.2 or apply [this patch](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/commit/7f6b1143fd0151fd885e3f1ae3a4b7c19d3e69d3) manually, which only involves one new line to the copy task:

```
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*' // <-- New line
                ]
            }]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

yeoman 1.1.2 does not seem to work with the answer above.

Change your Gruntfile.js and add:

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        '*.html',
        'views/{,*/}*.html',
        'bower_components/**/*',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'fonts/*',
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: ['generated/*']
    }, {                                                   <--- add this start
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts',
        src: '*.*'
    }]                                                     <--- end add
  },
  styles: {
```

Add a new block that copies the fonts out of the bower components into the dist directory. 
Replace bootstrap with sass-bootstrap if you use the sass distribution.

Comment: My fonts are in `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts`.

Comment: it worked for me, i did it to for awesome-font  and it work perfectly ! ;) thank

Answer (score 5):

That's a [bug](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/149). For now the easiest would be to just copy them manually over to the fonts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Copy fonts from *app/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap*

To *app/fonts*

In application.scss change **$icon-font-path**

From 
*$icon-font-path: "/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/"*

To 
*$icon-font-path: "/fonts/"*

Answer (score 0):

cssmin with root option replaces all relative paths.

you can deactivate the root option of cssmin in your Gruntfile.js

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    //root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me ;)

```
     copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        '**/*.html',
        'views/**/*.html',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: ['generated/*']
    },
        {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts',
        src: '*.*'
        },
        {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts',
        src: '*.*'
        }
     /*{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
      src: 'fonts*//*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }*/]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
},
```