# Optimizing Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am using grunt to merge reoccurring elements (footer, menu bar..) into pages of a simple website using bake.

In my root directory I call `grunt --force`

The process consumes a lot of time:

```
mocha:all 11.1s
concurrent:dist 400.1s
Total 414.5s
```

**Question:** How can I optimize the process and save time?

Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        config: {
            // Configurable paths
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist/public',
            prebake: 'appPreBake'
        },

        bake: {
            build: {
                options: {
                    basePath: 'appPreBake'
                },
                files: {
                    // Files that use templates should live in appPreBake.
                    // Add new files to the list below so that they will be
                    // added to the app/ folder, where they are served for the
                    // test server. When built they are compiled and put in the
                    // dist folder.
                    //
                    // grunt-bake adopts the formula:
                    // outputFile: templateFile
                    '<%= config.app %>/index.html': '<%= config.prebake %>/index.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>/first/index.html': '<%= config.prebake %>/first/index.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>/second/index.html': '<%= config.prebake %>/second/index.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>/third/index.html': '<%= config.prebake %>/third/index.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>/photos/index.html': '<%= config.prebake %>/photos/index.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>/about/index.html': '<%= config.prebake %>/about/index.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>blog.html': '<%= config.prebake %>blog.html'
                }
            }
        },

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            // We want to rerun bake every time we change a template file in
            // the prebake directory.
            bake: {
                files: ['appPreBake/**'],
                tasks: 'bake:build'
            },
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['bowerInstall']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jstest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['test:watch']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '<%= config.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        // Mocha testing framework configuration options
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
        bowerInstall: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
                ignorePath: '<%= config.app %>/'
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
            },
            html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            // There are several issues with this task in version 0.5.x. If you
            // are encountering problems where it hangs, claims to not find
            // files, or progresses on subsequent runs but emitting images of
            // size 0, uncomment this options object. It will stop caching and
            // this should fix the problem, although it will take longer.
            // For a more thorough discussion, see the following links:
            // https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/140
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175673/grunt-contrib-imagemin-output-fatal-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory
            //options: {
            //    cache: false
            //},
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //     dist: {}
        // },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.html',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/*.*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    // Have to manually add this copying to ensure that the
                    // glyphicons make it over.
                    // This solution comes from:
                    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572941/why-does-yeoman-build-without-glyphicons
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/fonts',
                    src: '*.*'
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
        if (target !== 'watch') {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer'
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:test',
            'mocha'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'bake',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: do you have a lot of images and svg files? it looks like your concurrent:dist task mainly copies style files and minimizes images. so that's your bottleneck (from what i can tell)

Comment: In total there are probably not more than 6 images

Comment: what happens when you just run grunt without --force?

Comment: At some point the process leads to mocha:all, which fails due to a timeout: "Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue."

Comment: i would try selectively running the different processes in your build to see what's happening. it doesn't make sense that concurrent:dist is taking that much time since its only doing 3 small tasks. have you tried just getting rid of those tasks to see what happens? (imgmin and svgmin aren't exactly mission critical tasks...)

Comment: I'm trying kicking out mocha and test, does that make sense? The new error message is "Arguments to path.join must be strings"

Comment: its hard for me to see what you are doing. try creating a custom grunt task like 'selective-test' in your grunt file and then only add and remove tasks in there and run that task (grunt selective-test) and see if you can pinpoint what's taking so much time. does that make sense?

Comment: According to the command line output, testing consumes the most of the time. How can I disable testing?

Comment: change the default task and remove test from it like so: `grunt.registerTask('default', ['newer:jshint','build']);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61394/discussion-between-bogus-and-gabereal).

Comment: when I try that, I get "Arguments to path.join must be strings", any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

first you need to see exactly where the problem is try running grunt using -v flag

```
grunt -v
```

and post the steps here. Please keep in mind to mark the step which will seem to stuck the whole process.

For time and performance try using [time-grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-grunt) plugin which is going to show you nice duration graphs for each task.

[image]